# Parâmetro async do jQuery.ajax está obsoleto, e agora?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Javascript e preciso fazer uma fila de requisições *ajax*, e preciso que uma seja feita após a outra, pois elas manipulam algumas variáveis do meu escopo. O parâmetro `async` do `jQuery.ajax` está obsoleto, como fazer com que as execuções sejam executadas em modo `sync`?

Não posso postar o código na integra pois pertence à empresa, mas posso exemplificar.

**O que eu tenho:**

```
(function(){
    var var10;
    var var20;
    var var30;
    var var40;

    function func10(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            success: function(data){
                /* Faça algo */
                var10 = data.algumacoisa;
            }
        })
    }

    function func20(p){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            data: {'algumacoisa': p},
            success: function(data){
                /* Faça algo */
                var20 = data.algumacoisa;
            }
        })
    }

    function func30(p){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            data: {'algumacoisa': p},
            success: function(data){
                /* Faça algo */
                var30 = data.algumacoisa;
            }
        })
    }

    function func40(p){
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/file',
            data: {'algumacoisa': p},
            success: function(data){
                /* Faça algo */
                var40 = data.algumacoisa;
            }
        })
    }

})();
```

---

**O que eu quero:**

Preciso que todas as funções sejam executadas na ordem `func10().func20(var10).func30(var20).func40(var30)` e também que sejam respeitados os `success`, ou seja após cada `success` execute a próxima função. Eu não tenho certeza se o método `$.when` faz isso, pois as funções não podem ser executadas paralelas.

---

**O que eu não quero:**

Não quero ter que chamar cada função no `success` da anterior:

```
function func2(p){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        data: {'algumacoisa': p},
        success: function(data){
            /* Faça algo */
            var20 = data.algumacoisa;
            func30(var20);
        }
    })
}
```

Pois se precisar colocar outra chamada no meio da fila, não quero sair vasculhando o código e ter que ficar alterando todas as chamas, quero apenas mexer na fila, por exemplo:

```
func10().func15(var10).func20(var15).func30(var20).func40(var30)
```

---

**É possível fazer isso? Se sim, qual é a melhor forma? Se não, Porque?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes ter uma array com a lista de funções que queres executar e ir correndo/esvaziando a lista como uma callback.

A ideia seria:

```
var funcArray = [function (data) {
    /* Faça algo */
    return data.algumacoisa;
}, function (data) {
    /* Faça algo */
    return data.algumacoisa;

}, function (data) {
    /* Faça algo */
    return data.algumacoisa;

}, function (data) {
    /* Faça algo */
    return data.algumacoisa;
}];

function tratadorAJAX(dataAnterior, next){
    if (!next) return;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/file',
        data: {'dataAnterior': dataAnterior},
        success: function(data){
            var proximaData = next(data);
            tratadorAJAX(proximaData, funcArray.pop());
        }
    })
}
tratadorAJAX(dataInicial, funcArray.pop());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
status = (function(){ 
    funcaoMain();
 });

verificando = status.done(function () {
    funcaoOptional();
});
concluindo = verificando.done(function () {
    funcaoterceira();
});
```

Comment: Valeu a intenção, mas isso não funciona com requisições `jQuery.ajax`, pois elas retornam um objeto antes do termino da execução. Ou seja a instrução `if(funcaoa)` ia retornar true e iria começar a executar a `funcaob`, porém a `funcaoa` ainda estaria em execução.

Comment: Pois é amigo, ai está entrando na parte _O que eu não quero_ da pergunta, porque vou ter que colocar a chamada nos _callback's_ de cada requisição.

Comment: ou voce pode chamar a primeira funcao inicializando um objeto como : `status = function()...` em seguida  `status.done(function () {`

Comment: [Edita sua resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/60835/edit) colocando esse exemplo de forma funcional. :D

Comment: tenta ai agora...